# samsung tab 3 cannot retrieve keyboard

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab

My daughter got a new samsung tab it was working with no problems , she dowmloaded a few apps then the keyboard went , so i went to check the settings and there was no option to retrieve it. i went into the playstore to add another but kept getting an error message which wouldnt allow me to install anything, 
i done a factory reset thinking it would wipe everything off and retrieve the keyboard which i didnt i m left with no keyboard and having to try and speak each command which is very difficult and doesnt work ,
can anyone offer a way round this ?

Comment: We'd like to help, and to do that we need a little more detail on the problem you're describing. When the keyboard "went", what exactly did you see? When did it happen? What error message did you get?

Comment: What happens when you go to Settings > Language and Input...? Is there any mention of ANY keyboard you have installed (you've tried others too right?)? You may need to just enable the keyboard. What happens when you click on an editable text box? Did she install any non market apps, anything Warez like at all that may have corrupted the device? I'm not clear at all on what you mean by 'went' and what steps you have tried. We need more detail.

Comment: the keyboard went after my daughter had installed a few apps via playstore, my daughter then said she could not type anymore as the keyboard had gone, the only option was to talk into a mic on the screen, so i tried to download another keyboard and got an error message 101 or 110 something like that . When i go into language input there is no mention of any keyboard just voice control, after this i completed a factory reset which didnt fix any problem as they keyboard will not inatall

Comment: sorry i dont know what non market apps are , im new to the samsung

Comment: Well there are apps in the Play Store (used to be called Market, sorry that's my bad) or the Amazon store etc. Then you can 'side load' applications downloaded from other sites. Some are very legit e.g. Android Police might have the installer for Google Search or such, but other less legal sites may have paid apps for free. Many are cracked and full of spyware, malware etc! Is it the 'Samsung' keyboard that came with the device? http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-tab/795688-unknown-error-code-during-application-install-110-a.html May be a hardware issue for '110'.

Answer (score 1):

I've run out of space  in comments so let's look at some options:

1) Go to Settings > Apps then go to Google Play Store and 'Uninstall Updates'. Then let the Play Store automatically update. Try downloading another keyboard.

2) If you have error 110 it MAY be hardware related.  [Thread on similar issue](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-tab/795688-unknown-error-code-during-application-install-110-a.html)
You may need to contact the seller or Samsung on this issue.

3) If you have error 101 then perhaps  [Google Play Services is to blame](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en_GB) try installing this from the link provided, reboot and try installing another keyboard.

4) Go to Settings > Apps and see if 'Samsung Keyboard' or similar is there at all, it MAY be disabled or something simple like that! (It will say 'disabled' beside it) You can go into it an click enable in this case.

5) See if you can download any apps at all from the Play Store. Pick something popular like "Facebook" or something from a reliable source. If this also fails there is somthing more fundemental wrong here.

6) If you are a bit more adventurous you could pop to XDA Devlopers and ask someone to post the APK (android application package, basically the app to be installed) for your keyboard and see if you can install it. This is a bit more advanced and I think best left til last resort for now. I'll talk you through it if you think it is a valid option. "Side Loading" is the term to look up!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you have to touch the bit that actually says default keyboard not the greyed out button below. So
`Settings, language and input`. Tap the header default and then slide the use onscreen keyboard button to turn the keyboard back on.

Answer (score 0):

The user manual advised to restart the tablet it becomes slow or unresponsive and my keyboard reappeared. The slide out  icon / split screen function had stopped working on mine as well, that has started again too.